# Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[mysql]' – installing ruby gem through Chef Solo

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-solo

Using Chef 10.24.0, when including the `database` [cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/database),

```
include_recipe "mysql::server"
include_recipe "database::mysql"
```

the `mysql` gem fails to install, with the following output:

```
[2013-03-10T19:54:29+00:00] INFO: Processing chef_gem[mysql] action install (mysql::ruby line 36)

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[mysql]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `last' for #<Gem::AvailableSet:0x00000002b25be0>

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:36:in `from_file'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/database/recipes/mysql.rb:20:in `from_file'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/scafandru/recipes/database.rb:11:in `from_file'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb

 36: chef_gem "mysql"

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:36:in `from_file'

chef_gem("mysql") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "mysql"
  cookbook_name :mysql
  recipe_name "ruby"
end


================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/scafandru/recipes/database.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
chef_gem[mysql] (mysql::ruby line 36) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Gem::AvailableSet:0x00000002b25be0>

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:36:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/database/recipes/mysql.rb:20:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/scafandru/recipes/database.rb:11:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:

 29:  include_recipe "build-essential"
 30:  include_recipe "mysql::client"
 31:  
 32:  node['mysql']['client']['packages'].each do |mysql_pack|
 33:    resources("package[#{mysql_pack}]").run_action(:install)
 34:  end
 35:  
 36>> chef_gem "mysql"
 37:  

[2013-03-10T19:54:31+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-03-10T19:54:31+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-03-10T19:54:31+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-03-10T19:54:31+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: chef_gem[mysql] (mysql::ruby line 36) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Gem::AvailableSet:0x00000002b25be0>
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Attempting to reduce the all variables that could cause the installation to fail, I discarded the `database` cookbook, and constrained to the RubyGem installation in the `mysql::ruby` [recipe](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/mysql#readme)

```
include_recipe "mysql::server"
include_recipe "mysql::ruby"
```

but the error was equivalent.

Same applies for the simplest `gem_package` [install](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_package.html):

```
gem_package 'mysql' do
  options "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
end
```

I'm out of ideas, can anyone please shed some light into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After downgrading to the [latest pre-2.0 version (1.8.5)](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update/versions) of RubyGems, everything works fine.

This issue will most likely be [addressed in RubyGems 2.0.3](https://twitter.com/evanphx/status/310893209360424960).

Comment: This seems to have cropped up again with v 2.1.9